# which version of doctrine is used in practical symfony tutorial? doctrine 1.2 or doctrine 2?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, version

which version of doctrine is used in practical symfony 1.4 tutorial? doctrine 1.2 or doctrine 2?

tutorial link

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03

the documentation did not mention the doctrine version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Afaik Symfony 1.4 ships with doctrine 1.2 so i guess the tutorial also talkes about doctrine 1.2.

Symfony 2 will ship with Doctrine 2

Comment: Yup. Having just completed the tutorial myself, it's definitely doctrine 1.2 for symfony 1.4.